# Page break which will stay one the same page - quarto docx

Tags: r, docx, quarto

I want to create a report with Quarto in a DOCX document. I have a problem with creating a page break which will stay one the same page.

yaml

```
---
format: 
  docx: 
    fig-width: 12
    fig-height: 8
    reference-doc: custom-reference-doc_landscape.docx
execute: 
  echo: false
  eval: true
  output: false
  warning: false
  message: false
editor: source
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

```
`r table1` 

{{< pagebreak >}}

`r table2`
```

This works fine if there is at least one empty line after table 1. If the table fills the entire page, then the page break falls onto the next page with the addition of an empty page. Manually, I can solve my problem by changing the font size of the page break to really small one, but I am searching for some other solution.

Is it possible to change the font size of {{< pagebreak >}} with some code mybe?